# React native Custom font is not working in android

Tags: react-native, custom-font

I have followed all the procedures to add and use a custom font in my react native app but it is not working. Below is what I have followed.

1. Added assets/fonts under the root directory and added ttf fonts to it

[Pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdrA4.png)

2. Created react-native.config.js and added the below code

   module.exports = {
   assets : ['./assets/fonts']
   }
3. some sources said to add the below in package.json. Added it as well

   "rnpm": {
   "assets": ["./assets/fonts"]
   }
4. Now, inside my component I am exactly using the same ttf name for font family style.

   > style= {styles.textStyles}
   >
   > const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   > textStyles : {
   > fontFamily : 'Good Feeling Sans',
   > fontSize : 20,
   > fontWeight : 'bold',
   > margin : 10
   > } })

6. Ran "npx react-native link" and it was linked successfully

[Linked Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rkhX.png)

7.Ran "npx react-native run-android" and I see no change in the font. :( Any idea why it does not reflect

Comment: expo or bare rn?

Comment: Bare React native app @anthonywillismuñoz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to declare your font style **without `fontWeight` parameter**, so please try to declare your font style as:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
      textStyles : { 
          fontFamily : 'Good Feeling Sans', 
          fontSize : 20, 
          margin : 10 
      } 
})
```

In stead of manipulating with `fontWeight`, you can use special prepared fonts for this (ttf files with weight variants). But if you really need the `fontWeight` you can try to declare it with number value, like in example: `fontWeight:800`

It was a problem with `fontWeight` I noticed in previous versions of React Native (< 0.60), maybe still present nowadays.

Make sure you also placed your font files in proper folder, accessible to your app. In your pic, assets/fonts is misplaced I believe, it should be placed under `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` folder.

Comment: Great! Removing font Weight worked for me. The fonts are already placed under android/app/src/main/assets/fonts. Thanks @deevee

Answer (score 0):

Just go to android folder and create android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
in that folder just drop your custom fonts.
[image]

Comment: Yup. Fonts are already placed there. Removing Font Weight worked for me. @anthony willis muñoz. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Rename the font file name to lowercase & Remove - from file name.
2. Run npx react-native link
3. Restart app npx react-native run-android